# R: add value from another data frame by finding same values in two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

Imagine there are two data frames.

`df1` has several thousands of observations and looks like this:

```
Num     Code
00001   1
00002   2
00003   3
00004   1
00005   1
...     ...
```

`df2` is short and lists all codes available, giving them description:

```
Code    Code_name
1       Short
2       Medium
3       Long
```

I want new data frame to be like `df1`, but with code names attached:

```
Num     Code      Code_name
00001   1         Short
00002   2         Medium
00003   3         Long
00004   1         Short
00005   1         Short
...     ...
```

Found kind of same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697171/compare-two-data-frames-with-different-column-names-and-update-first-data-frame) only for Python. A better way is may be to create some kind of a loop...
This seems to be an easy task by I am to newbie for R, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use merge() from the base package

```
merge(df1, df2, by = 'Code', all.x=T, all.y=F)
```